# How to configure Emacs use an input method provided by MS Windows 10?

Tags: windows, emacs

on MS Windows 10, the system's input method is powerful and easy to use.
There is also a Chinese input method in Emacs. I tried eim and other input methods, and think only the system's input method is friendly and easy to use.

Maybe there are two ways:

1. configure through Emacs's input-method interface.
   I couldn't find out the solution after read the Emacs manual.
2. Modify the key-event's handle flow.

Can I do this by configuring the system or by configuring Emacs?